# Sharing Cubase Audio over Microsoft Teams and being able to speak over it and hear others

Tags: cubase, sharing

When I am on Microsoft Teams I want to be able to share my Cubase screen and playback with my team members. But they only see the screen and not the hear the Audio. If I set the realse Audio when Cubase not in focus then the music stops when I switch to Teams.
Does anybody know how to overcome this problem.
I want to play Cubase music, talk over it and and be able to hear others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks @Matt  for your time and answer. I tried to do the same with Zoom and it worked on the first try!! All you need to do is to select the standard driver which comes with Windows 10 with Cubase and then in Zoom say you are using the Computer sound. There is a button to click and that was it. (which has a very large latency which is ok for this kind of work) As this worked I never looked at Teams again.

Comment: Thank you for this information.  I'm glad Zoom works for you. I'll keep that in mind, next time I want to do sth. similar.

Answer (score 0):

I did experiments myself with another DAW and had quite similar problems. Either you allow applications to have exclusive access to audio devices (default setting) then either the DAW or Teams work but not both at the same time. Or you uncheck this option in Windows audio properties and either Teams or the DAW or the audio drivers crash (well, that's what's happened on my side). Long story short: I don't think you can make it work on one computer.

But you could try to have 2 computers (or a smartphone with suitable audio jack adapter) - each with it's own active Teams instance. On the DAW computer you share the screen but route the final audio mixdown (incl. your microphone) out and feed that into the line-in of the second computer. The headphones could also be plugged into the 2nd computer. I have not tested this but it could work. I think you can even use the same Teams account to enter the same call twice. Good luck!

**UPDATE:**

I found time to try it myself and it works! One detail problem: you can either plug in headphones to computer 2 to hear your call participants or plug in to computer 1 for monitoring. You can use a mixer if you want to have both.
I used Audition by the way, and added an amplify effect to mic and clicked the monitor track option, so the sound will be routed live to my output. Logging in twice to a Teams call does indeed work.

However, I still don't know: does this work for you with Cubase too? (At the moment, I cannot imagine why not). Please give feedback, I've put a lot of work into this.

**One More Thing**

You have zero control over the audio quality and automatic level adjustments in Teams. Judging by the feedback from my audience I ruled out Teams for anything musically. If audio quality does matter for you, I suggest looking for a better solution. Podcasting software for example. I heard Audio Hijack for Mac is great and it offers live streaming. People could listen to the live stream while being in the Teams call. However you need to deal with delays. But this is always the case: either high quality audio and delays or bad quality and realtime transmission. You cannot have the best of both worlds.